# ExtJS manipulating propertygrid source information

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I'm using a propertygrid in a similar fashion to a form, rendering a button in the propertygrid tbar to generate an AJAX request, passing the source information to a back-end function that runs a SQL script.

The process of getting the source information to the back-end is proving troublesome, however; while looking at the information in the browser debug console, the result looks like it can be iterated (sample info from console below):

```
[CNC: "", Cutter_ID: "", Dimension: "", ID: "71",
Internal_Finish: "Standard White", Item_No: "4", Material_ID: "N/A",
Production_Item_Type_ID: "Frame(s)", Production_Notes: "", Qty: "1",
Ready_by_Date: "31 Dec 2014", Survey_Notes: "",
Thickness_Depth: "95", Type_of_Work_ID: "Complete New"]
```

Selecting individual items can be done, i.e. I can get and set `source['Qty']`, for instance.

I cannot, however, pass the information in a manageable format; neither can I encode (or decode) the information from the source to JSON.

I would like to at least iterate through the source and append the information to a string, which is then encoded to JSON to pass to the back-end.

How does the propertygrid source work as a data source, since I clearly don't understand it correctly? What method can I employ to generate JSONable information from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property grid's [getSource](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-getSource) method returns the source as an object, loop through it to append information

Sample fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/58o